# Not able to fetch the ZIP file in Helm chart

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Inside my helm chart in a custom directory which has a zip file and the same file needs to pass to API which is being called from a sh file on post-install hook. I am trying to get the file as below but it returns the content of zip file which is not supported by the API.

> value: {{ .Files.Get "scripts/ParameterAndSource.zip" }}

How to access the file location directly so that file can be available to the API instead of file content.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your shell script is run in a Job. If so I think you could is put the file in a ConfigMap and then mount the ConfigMap as a Volume for your Job.

(I don't have a Job-based example but for a Deployment see https://github.com/ryandawsonuk/secrets-treasurehunt/blob/master/charts/treasurehunt/templates/config.yaml and  and https://github.com/ryandawsonuk/secrets-treasurehunt/blob/master/charts/treasurehunt/templates/deployment.yaml )

Comment: I am able to access the zip file now but the issue is , I am using post-install hook and my container does not come up because it is waiting for job and my job doesn’t succeed because it is waiting for container to come up. It is becoming cyclical dependency

Comment: Does everything start correctly if you remove the post-install hook? Do you mean the install fails and you never get a release name back from helm? There is meant to be a defined lifecycle in which hooks are executed and an order for object creation so as to avoid cyclic dependencies.

Comment: Maybe the hook is running too early?

Comment: it works fine if i remove the job running on post install hook. But job itself calls the api which would be available once container is up but contaner does not come up as job is not completed. it does not matter when job is getting executed as i am continuously doing ping to get the status

Comment: Have you tried asking on the helm slack channel? I don't think that's intended behaviour - most likely somebody there could confirm and advise whether to raise an issue on helm project